# Where should I create static records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, I have users and roles. Some of the roles should always exist, such as "Admin". Where should I do something like:

```
Role.create(name: 'Admin')
```

In the past, I've always placed these lines in a migration to ensure it ends up on the deployed server. This sometimes leads to issues as a developer may forget to instead write it like:

```
Role.where(name: 'Admin').first_or_create
```

Should they go in the `seeds.rb` file? I have generally used the seeds file for local development "playing around" data.

**What is the Rails Best Practice for generating static data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `seed.rb` is the perfect place for that. Migrations are not meant to be used for anything other than convenience during development and should never be relied upon for really anything.

From the docs:

> To add initial data after a database is created, Rails has a built-in
>   'seeds' feature that makes the process quick and easy. This is
>   especially useful when reloading the database frequently in
>   development and test environments. It's easy to get started with this
>   feature: just fill up db/seeds.rb with some Ruby code, and run rails
>   db:seed

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

Comment: What's the best way to ensure the seeds gets run during a deployment? Last thing we want is to forget to run the seeds file. I assume it's also really common to make it so the seeds file can be run multiple times without having an effect right (using `first_or_create`)?

Comment: If you're using something like capistrano you can do something like `after_deploy rake db:seed`. I don't remember the exact syntax, but that's the idea. And yes, seeds can and probably should be set up in a way that it's safe to run them multiple times.

Comment: What if in the event something needs to be destroyed? If a deploy were to run the seeds again at the end, objects would be created.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with creating a migration for doing something like that, if you need to do a one time deletion of something.

Comment: My concern is that if I use the seeds file to create the data, and the migration deletes the data. The next time the seeds file gets run it will recreate it when I might not want that. Yes?

The seeds file would be run on each deploy for example if more data was added to it later. I'm starting to think migrations solely might be the way to go?

Comment: Well, there is no one size fits all. If you think it's best for your project go with that solution, there are no hard rules about what's best.

Answer (score 1):

Rails way is to use `seeds.rb` - simple and useful.

In my opinion, data migrations are needed only in situations when you must add data to existing records (after inserting new column with default value, for example)